# My texture paint is gray

Tags: texture-painting

I want to paint the Rainbow on the wall, I added the texture and unwrapped the wall but the rainbow does not have any colors and it doesn't paint on the wall
Any help would be appreciated[image]

Comment: So do you want to put an image texture on the wall, or do you actually want to paint something? What is this for? Do you just want to put an image on a wall or does the image have some transparent parts where it should be possible to see the original wall material behind it? The screenshot is not very clear, maybe it would be better to take one from an angle the wall will be visible in your renders, so it's easier to get an idea what this is all about.

Comment: maybe pack your image and share the file (only the wall)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Other that sharing the file, here we need to ask if you have checked that the face normals are pointing outward and for the settings of the texture in the texture tab, if you've set to use alpha or calculate alpha. Retest the anomaly with a simple plane with the same attempt to stencil paint onto a blank texture.